# USB 3.0, Screen Brightness, and Realtek HD Audio (13.04)

Tags: drivers, nvidia, sound, brightness, realtek

I'm VERY new to linux, have played around a bit every now and then, but never really got the hang of it. I'm now tired of MS, so decided to give it a fighting chance. I have a Acer Aspire 5750G, Intel Core i7, GeForce GT540M, Nvidia Optimus and 8GB RAM - I would LOVE to know how to install my USB 3.0 Drivers, my Realtek HD Audio, aswell as how to restore my ability to adjust my screen brightness??? My apologies if that is a tall order :-) Like i said, I'm very new, and dont know much of linux, but I'm a quick learner...

Your help is greatly appreciated!!

Riaan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Wasabi-RSM Welcome to the Forums! I can only answer one of your questions. For the realtek audio you need to go to their website (  http://www.realtek.com/downloads ) and look for their Linux/Unix driver section and download the one that applies for your system. Once you dl and unzip it there is an executable text file. Run it in terminal when prompted. When that is done restart your computer and it should be working. If you can not run the install script by double clicking it you many need to go into the file menu (hover your mouse at the top left of the desktop) and go to Preferences->Behavior and enable the running of scripts from the desktop.

As for your monitor brightness question, there are many threads on here about this and I have never seen one with a definitive answer (one that works in most installs most of the time). Most solutions seem to be very specific to the hardware and software combo. All I can say is I have tried many solutions and I still can not control the brightness of my monitor either, Luckily it is always at max brightness. Long story short, dig around these forums and see if someone with the same/similar laptop has found a solution and start there. Best of luck to you.